# Cypher FOREACH MERGE not hitting the index

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got a following parametrized Cypher query:

```
MERGE (p:Person {pid: {personId}}) ON CREATE SET p.value=rand()
MERGE (c:Page {url: {pageUrl}}) ON CREATE SET c.value=rand()
MERGE p-[:REL]->c
FOREACH (tagValue IN {tags} | 
  MERGE (t:Tag {value:tagValue})
  MERGE c-[:hasTag]->t)
```

This is very slow, the profiling shows:

```
    EmptyResult
      |
      +UpdateGraph(0)
        |
        +Eager(0)
          |
          +UpdateGraph(1)
            |
            +Eager(1)
              |
              +UpdateGraph(2)

    +----------------+------+--------+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |       Operator | Rows | DbHits |                  Identifiers |                                                                        Other |
    +----------------+------+--------+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |    EmptyResult |    0 |      0 |                              |                                                                              |
    | UpdateGraph(0) |    1 |  79222 |                              |                                                                      Foreach |
    |       Eager(0) |    1 |      0 |                              |                                                                              |
    | UpdateGraph(1) |    1 |      5 |           p, c,   UNNAMED163 |                                                                 MergePattern |
    |       Eager(1) |    1 |      0 |                              |                                                                              |
    | UpdateGraph(2) |    1 |     14 |                   p, p, c, c | 
MergeNode; {personId}; :Person(pid); MergeNode; {pageUrl}; :Page(url) |
    +----------------+------+--------+------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

    Total database accesses: 79241
```

As you can see, it's apparently not using the index I've defined on :Tag(value)

Any ideas how to fix this? I'm running out of ideas and I'm starting to think this might be connected to https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/861

FYI, the MERGEs are really convenient for me and this query perfectly matches (or would if it worked:) the usage I need for data ingestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, does it use an index if you use UNWIND instead of FOREACH?

```
MERGE (p:Person {pid: {personId}}) ON CREATE SET p.value=rand()
MERGE (c:Page {url: {pageUrl}}) ON CREATE SET c.value=rand()
MERGE p-[:REL]->c
WITH c
UNWIND {tags} AS tagValue
MERGE (t:Tag {value:tagValue})
MERGE c-[:hasTag]->t
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. UNWIND does hit the index indeed; I didn't understand the usage before.

Comment: great. Do you see better performance using UNWIND then? How do you know it's hitting the index? 

Could you let me know what we can improve on the UNWIND documentation page so it's more obvious what it can be used for - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-unwind.html#unwind-create-nodes-from-a-collection-parameter - we have an example similar to this one at the end showing how to MERGE a collection of events

Comment: Yes, I see better performance. Profiling shows 70 db hits, I assume that means it's hitting the index :) Do you think this query could be further optimized?

I kind of missed UNWIND completely, I skimmed through the docs so it was not apparent to me I could use it. FOREACH sounded like an obvious choice.