# Need help to optimize neo4j cypher CREATE and MERGE queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher, bitcoin, blockchain

I am parsing bitcoin blockchain, the whole idea is to build a node graph that looks like this (address)-[redeemed]->(tx)-[sent]->(address) so I can see how bitcoin addresses are related to each other. The problem is the execution time, sometimes it takes a few minutes to import just one transaction. Besides, some of these queries are too long, like few thousands of lines, and won't execute at all. I have read a few articles on how to optimize match queries, but found almost nothing about create and merge. I saw a few guys here recommending to use UNWIND and send as much data as possible as parameters, to make queries shorter, but I have no idea how to implement this in my query.

Here is example of my query: http://pastebin.com/9S0kLNey

Comment: I think you are asking too much

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the following simple query, passing the string [parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.3/cypher-parameters.html) "hash", "time", "block", and "confs"; and a collection parameter named "data":

```
CREATE (tx:Tx {hash: {hash}, time: {time}, block: {block}, confirmations: {confs}})
FOREACH(x IN {data} |
  MERGE (addr:Address {address: x.a})
  CREATE (addr)-[:REDEEMED {value: x.v}]->(tx)
);
```

The values to use for the string parameters should be obvious.

Each "data" element would be a map containing an address ("a") and a value ("v"). For example, here is a snippet of the "data" collection that would correspond to the data in your sample query:

```
[
  {a: "18oBAMgFaeFcZ5bziaYpUpsNCJ7G8EgH8g", v: "240"},
  {a: "192W3HUVDyrp6ewvisHSijcx9f5ZoarrwX", v: "410"},
  {a: "18tnEFy4usZvpMZLnjBFPjbmLKEzqPz958", v: "16.88"},
  ...
]
```

This query *should* run faster than your original sample, but I don't know how much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed reply, i'll try this and post my results here. Also I have 2 types of relathionships: (addr)-[:REDEEMED {value}]->(tx) and (tx)-[:SENT {value}]->(addr). So do I need to make 2 different collections for this query? Like data_sent and data_redeemed with 2 FOREACH in my query, or maybe I can pass both in one collection using one foreach somehow?

Comment: If every `SENT` relationship is always the same as a `REDEEMED` relationship (except for the directionality), then you do not need both relationship types. A relationship can be traversed in either direction.

Comment: ok, just tried it and it seems that I'm expirienced the same issue [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853532/cypher-foreach-merge-not-hitting-the-index)
Foreach is really slow, I have to wait for half an hour and its still running. Exactly the same query but with UNWIND instead of foreach ececuting in 70ms, but i didn't found how to unwind multiple collections (for :SENT and :REDEEMED relationships). Execution time of my previous query with the same data was ~85ms.

Comment: nope, they are completely different. One is sending coins and another is recieving. There can be one sender and multiple recievers in one transaction and vice versa

Comment: You are probably missing constraints on `:Address(address)`

Comment: You can also use UNWIND instead of foreach if you already have all the addresses in your database. `UNWIND {data} as x MATCH (addr:Address {address: x.a}) CREATE (addr)-[:REDEEMED {value: x.v}]->(tx)`

Comment: @MichaelHunger No I haven't. I am parsing bitcoin blockchain to fill my database with transactions and addresses, all i have is one transaction and a bunch of addresses for each query. Each address is unique. Some of them may already be in db, so I just need to create relationship, but most of them don't. And there is index on :Address(address), but I'll try with constraint.

Comment: @MichaelHunger I know about UNWIND but the problem is I need to pass to it two collections somehow, like `WITH tx UNWIND {data_sent} AS s, {data_redeemed} AS r` but I don't know if its even possible. Unlike the FOREACH I can't use 2 unwind in my query, like `WITH tx
UNWIND {data_sent} AS s
MERGE (as:Address {address: s.a})
CREATE (t)-[:SENT {value: s.v}]->(as)
WITH tx
UNWIND {data_redeemed} AS r
MERGE (ar:Address {address: r.a})
CREATE (ar)-[:REDEEMED {value: r.v}]->(t)` because it doubles REDEEMED relationship So I gues I need another query for the REDEEMED with another tx match, right?